# Pressing the jump button also makes my character fire their weapon

Tags: unity, c#, input

In my game I want my player jump without firing their weapon, but when I press the button it jumps and also fires too in same moment.

In this Update method, I used Input.GetButton so my player will fire continuously while holding the button.

```
void Start () {
    isJumped = true;
}




// Update is called once per frame
void Update(){
    if (!transform.GetChild (0).gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth> ().hasDied) {

        if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1") && Time.time > firespeed && isJumped == true) {
                nextFire = myTime + firespeed;
                newProjectile = Instantiate (projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
                nextFire = nextFire - myTime;
                myTime = 0.0F;
                //  EnergyCharging ();
            }
        }
    }

void JumpButton(){
if(!transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().hasDied){
        if (grounded) {
            grounded = true;
            myRigidBody.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpPower), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            if(myRigidBody.velocity.y > jumpPower){
                myRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2 (0, jumpPower);
            }
            animator.SetBool ("isGrounded", grounded);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a public boolean variable, set it to true when player jumps, check this variable in update method, if it is true, don't fire.

Comment: Sorry azemda, I don't understand properly. I set it boolean but now what to do i don't get it.

Comment: Declare a boolean variable say, `isJumped`, in `JumpButton()` method, set it to false; and in `update()` method `if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1") && Time.time > speed && isJumped == true)`. Try this

Comment: Yeah i declare it now

Comment: Sorry azmeda, its not working my player is jump but now my firing mode is not working.

Comment: When he grounds, set `isJumped` to `true` or set it initially to `true` in Start() method

Comment: Yeah i set it true but now my bullet fire from one click. (Holding the button and continuously fire not works)

Comment: Its again working same jump and fire works on same moment.

Comment: You should show us how `JumpButton()` gets called, since we can't see that in the code snippet you've shared. Is this being fired by an on-screen UI button, or by a different part of the script?

Comment: Sir, JumpButton() not called, its being fired from on-screen UI button, i have only this JumpButton() which i paste it here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a checklist of things to check:

1. Does the game use the same button for jumping and attacking ? I don't see the code that looks if the player has pressed the jump button anywhere.
2. Is "isJumped" turned false at any point by something ? In the code you provided it doesn't. And what's the point of a "isJumped" bool, if the Jump method doesn't change it ?
3. According to the code you provided, if "isJumped" isn't changed elsewhere, it will always be true, and the player will always be able to attack, even if he is jumping.

P.S. In the "JumpButton()" method you check if grounded is true, and if it is you turn it to true... It already is true because if it weren't, it wouldn't pass the 'if'. So it's useless to assign this bool to true right after the 'if', because it's going to be true anyway.

Comment: Re:1) I'm guessing JumpButton is called by an on-screen UI button when it's tapped. A tap also gets registered as a click, and click is mapped to "Fire1" by default. So they're the same input, via a slightly roundabout route.

Comment: Yes, this might be it. But even if it isn't there is still the problem with the "isJumped" bool. The OP's problem is that the character can shoot while he jumps. In his Update() function, in the 'if' he adds as a condition that "isJumped" is true, and he sets it to true in the Start() method, which acts as a constructor of sorts. So if he doesn't change it to false at any other part of the code, it's always going to be true. But even if there is code elsewhere that changes it to false, if firing requires jumping being true, the character will always be able to fire while jumping...

Comment: JumpButton() method not called anywhere rather than this code which i paste it here and its a UI button, so i press anywhere in the screen its jump and fire in same moment. so i just want i press the jump button its only jump.